# Raster Calculator returning NoData when using exponents on sinus

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator

I'm trying to use the raster calculator to calculate:
Power("sinSLOPE.tif",1.30)

sinSLOPE contains values from -1 to 1 and no NoData points. The Calculator however returns a raster with values from 0 to 1 and a lot of NoData values. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using the Power tool https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/power.htm directly and not the raster calculator?

Comment: Yes, but as far as i understand it the power tool only allows you to exponentiate one raster with another and not simply to specify an exponent. I could create a raster with a cell value of 1.3. True. But I also want the raster calculator to work.

Comment: In the example for the power tool (OutRas = Power(InRas1, 2) the inputs are a raster and a constant.. both parameters are *in_raster_or_constant*, so theoretically you could use 2 constants but I'm sure that the tool wouldn't like that. The reason I mention using the tool directly is to test if there's something wrong with your inputs or with raster calculator. Can you find a location where you're expecting a value and getting null, use the identify tool with 'all layers' to reveal the raster values and post a screen shot of that in your question please.

Comment: What is the data type of the output raster? Does it support negative values?

Comment: Are you using the Spatial Anslyst with ArcGIS Pro or with ArcMap?

Comment: Raster calculator doesn't work with complex numbers Power(-1,1.3) = -058-0.81×i  It replaces output by None